# Is timer to update microsoft graph change subscription suitable for production code

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am following the example in the link https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications and creating and updating the notification subscription using a timer class.

```
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult<string> Get()
{
    var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient();

    var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
    sub.ChangeType = "updated";
    sub.NotificationUrl = config.Ngrok + "/api/notifications";
    sub.Resource = "/users";
    sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
    sub.ClientState = "SecretClientState";

    var newSubscription = graphServiceClient
        .Subscriptions
        .Request()
        .AddAsync(sub).Result;

    Subscriptions[newSubscription.Id] = newSubscription;

    if(subscriptionTimer == null)
    {
        subscriptionTimer = new Timer(CheckSubscriptions, null, 5000, 15000);
    }

    return $"Subscribed. Id: {newSubscription.Id}, Expiration: {newSubscription.ExpirationDateTime}";
}
```

But I have noticed the timer does not always get triggered(eg: network related issue/ after a fresh deployment of the code).

Is there a better way to replace this timer?

I have heard about webjobs in azure, is it possible to replace this timer with azure webjobs? If so can someone point me to some documentation on how?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you're using `ASPNET`, if you're using the `ASPNETCORE` version, since 2.x, you can have background services that you could run every X hours to resubscribe (update) the subscriptions. That's what we're using (and we're on Azure). I would guess webjobs could do the trick, but I have not used them yet. You could also have an external service that calls one of your endpoints every X hours (like a CRON job) .

hope this helps!
JS